# Scrapy does not load the page

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I use scrapy, the `start_url` has the following structure:

```
https://www.yoox.com/us/men/shoponline/accessories_mc#/dept=men&gender=U&page=1&season=X
```

Scrapy does not load the page:

```
scrapy shell https://www.yoox.com/us/men/shoponline/accessories_mc#/dept=men&gender=U&page=1&season=X
```

Maybe due to the fact that the link is missing the symbol `?`. What is not correct?

Comment: Can you give an example of concrete page and how it is not loaded in details?

Comment: def start_requests(self):
        
       yield scrapy.Request(url=self.job['start_url'], callback=self.parse)

Comment: No, I meant link that you process. `http://......`? And what do you get instead of proper answer?

Comment: scrapy shell [link](https://www.yoox.com/us/men/shoponline/accessories_mc#/dept=men&gender=U&page=1&season=X)

Comment: This link uses a lot of extra requests. Since scrapy from scratch does not load them, probably you can think about Scrapy Splash/Selenium solutions. Or just check what api-requests are done on your page and use them directly in your code.

Comment: I can not write the link correctly in the post

Comment: How can I check the api-requests that are running on the page, and use them in my code? May be an example. I beg you very much)))

Answer (score 1):

As [@vezunchik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7106850/vezunchik) said your data is loaded dynamically by JavaScript from another link. But you can use that link directly in your code: `https://www.yoox.com/US/shoponline?dept=men&gender=U&page=1&season=X&clientabt=SmsMultiChannel_ON%2CSizeIsocode_ON%2CNewDelivery_ON`

I found above link using Chrome Developer Tools and Network tab.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may not need splash as the other poster suggested. I would investigate using developer tools to see if you can access the API directly.

If you do need Splash check your settings and be sure you have copied in the middlewares and also set SPLASH_URL setting.

```
SPLASH_URL = 'http://194.182.69.110:8050'

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
}

SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
}
```

You should probably accept **gangabass** answer since he has resolved your issue without the need for any JavaScript processing. Which is always the correct answer do not use JS unless absolutely necessary.

Things like splash or Selenium should ALWAYS be a last line of defense against particular websites. For example on an ASP site it may be more beneficial to just use Selenium than to try and reverse engineer their requests. That is if they do not need large amounts of data. Selenium and Splash just don't work that well for scraping so they should only be used if absolutely required. Almost every website can be scraped without processing JavaScript if you analyze the requests. Most websites are using their own API that is undocumented to serve the front end of their website.

**Answer to updated question about loading the page with Scrapy shell. Your URL is not formed properly, or is malformed.**
This is your URL endpoint. You can send parameters to it by beginning with a question mark.
https://www.yoox.com/us/men/shoponline/accessories_mc#/

This is the arguments you want to send to the URL. It begins with a ? to signify the beginning of the arguments and an ampersand or & to add the next argument.
?dept=men&gender=U&page=1&season=X

There should be a ? right before debt.  ?dept=men&gender=U

Again you do probably shouldn't need to be using Splash for this. I would leave comments but not enough REP yet for me to do so. I've appended the answer to reflect the ongoing conversation.